# UIButton image cannot set properly by taking names from the NSArray

Tags: ios, uibutton, nsarray

Hello I have a problem like this. In my `ViewController` I have a delegate method like this

`

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{

        imgArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"water-dark.png",@"land-dark.png",@"animal-dark.png",@"air-dark.png",@"other-dark.png", nil];
button = (UIButton *)view;
if (button == nil)
{
    //no button available to recycle, so create new one
    //UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"page.png"];
    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 50, 50);
    button.layer.cornerRadius=button.frame.size.width/2.0;
    button.layer.borderWidth=2;
    button.clipsToBounds = YES;


    button.titleLabel.font = [button.titleLabel.font fontWithSize:15];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  }

  //set button label
  [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", index] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  NSString *strIndex=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",index];

  [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",      [imgArray objectAtIndex:[strIndex intValue]]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

  NSLog(@" CURRENT INDEX %i",index);

  return button;


}
```

`

Here Im lacing 5 buttons on `viewcontroller. Those 5 buttons titles are setting perfectly. I put the index number as the title. And now I want to get the image name from the`imgArray` and set each image to the button. But the problem is

it set only 0th button image and the 4th(5th) button image only. But when I try to print the image name by taking from the array. All print on each button properly.

What should be the reason for this? And how can I solve this problem. Please help me

This is the output that I get currently. But I need to fill all 5 buttons with images in the array.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure all the 3 non-showing images are named properly and have been added to the project?

Comment: yeas they are named correctly

Comment: OMG noo,, its not correctly added. Thank you so much you saved me :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey First Of all There is no need to take a Button and its click event instead you can just return view in `- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view` in this method as I listed beolw.
and ya of course you want its click event instead you can use its one of the delegates `- (void)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index`

This is your main method `viewForItemAtIndex()`

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view 
{
      view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 250)];
      ((UIImageView *)view).image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imgArray objectAtIndex:index]];
      view.alpha = 1.0;
      [view.layer setCornerRadius:125];
      [((UIImageView *)view).layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
      [((UIImageView *)view) setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
      view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
      return view;
}
```

Here the arrImages is declared in .h file of your view controller and assigning it in `viewDidLoad()` method i.e. `imgArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"water-dark.png",@"land-dark.png",@"animal-dark.png",@"air-dark.png",@"other-dark.png", nil];`

and for knowledge it is not necessary to write or assign array of images with `.png` after every image name like you can also write `imgArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"water-dark",@"land-dark",@"animal-dark",@"air-dark",@"other-dark", nil];`